# Algorithm to detect numbers that do not make sense

Tags: php, math

I am using an application that collects price data and makes sensible buying and selling prices each time data is retrieved. Now it can happen that the numbers are way to high or way too small because of how to system works. I can't do anything about this.

Now my question is, if I have an array of number like:

```
$prices = ['300','312','293','298','1025','12'];
```

What would be a good algorithm to get rid of the 12 and 1025? Note that a higher number appears far more often than a really low number so simply taking a average doesn't work.

I thought about taking a average of the whole array, looping through the array and checking for a differential percentage for each item and check if it under the threshold but I thought that this wouldn't be as accurate as I would like.

Comment: Sorry for the name of the question btw. Couldn't think of anything better...

Comment: You must provide more information. What do you want, check the difference between the last item and the previous, if > than xx, drop the last item?

Comment: It sounds like you should be looking at **median** prices rather than averages

Comment: Why don't you simply set a max_price and min_price and check if the price is between them or not?

Comment: So you're basically unsure what is an "abnormal" value...? Well, that heavily depends on the distribution of your numbers. Which you really should know upfront. You could do what you suggest, using an average and i.e. removing all values that are > 2 standard deviations away from the average. Of course you'd then need to check that the standard deviation is large enough (you wouldn't want 100, 101, 102, 101, 104 to remove 100 and 104, simply because it is "far" from the tight average. Right?

Comment: @enapupe, I want to calculate the average based on the last 5 items in  the array since they are the most recent. But sometimes I get values from the external server that basically do not fit in the context. I tried weighted averages but those do not work either...

Comment: first you need to strictly define what an outlier should look like. How do you know that `1025` really ISN'T the proper value and the rest are wrong because the sensor they came from is malfunctioning?

Comment: They way I decide if the number makes sense or not is basically by looking what values appear regularly. And the margin for error would basically be -+50 or so.

Comment: I would take a variable amount like 120% and 80%

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't any simple solution. Here is my advice. (1) Don't simply ignore the numbers which seem to be abnormal. Make them into a separate data stream which can be inspected. Any scheme to label abnormal values will inevitably have someone wondering what got thrown out. (2) The general topic is called "outlier detection" or "outlier filtering" -- a web search should turn up many references. Good luck & have fun.

Comment: Thanks Robert, your answer comment helped me a lot. I found a good one on Google :) Upvote for you my sir.

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about absolute numbers?

If I understood you correct there are multiple price lists so the average valid price could differ, it could be 1000 and some could be around 300 like in your example, my algorithm suggestion will work with both. You did not inform if the price would always be as close as in the examples or it could be higher if the price was higher.

I will split my answer in four parts, the first part will be for both situations (price difference is low at low values and high at high values). And the second part will be useful if the price difference will increase as the average valid price increases. The third part will be the whole algorithm for how you want to wrap it all together. The last part will be what to do at the first run.

### Part 1: Finding a value for validation processing

you say that you have a list of these numbers and that it retrieves new data all the time. The way I would suggest you do, is that if you subtract two numbers with each other and the absolute value.

Example:
300-312=|12|

With the number 12 we can conclude that both these prices are in the valid price range. Now let's take 3 other examples, one where both values are invalid and one where only one is invalid.

Example:
1025-12=|1013|

We can see that 1013 is no way an average price in this list, since both are invalid we have to test them both against a valid price. The algorithm will then remove them both.

Example:
300-12=|288|

We can see that 288 isn't a valid price either, the algorithm will remove 12.

### Part 2: validating a price with varying price differences

If you have lists where the average price could have a difference of 400, -50 and +50 in difference will give you bugs in your algorithm, therefore you need a way to determine this in a scalable way, that will make sure higher numbers can have higher differences in prices.

If the absolute value is **Higher** than 20%(or another number) of the average number of the two numbers, they would need further validation.

Example:
(300+312)/2=306 is the average number.
306*0.2=61,2

If you have a stored value of the highest and lowest valid number you could use 20% of their average to determine the threshold.
(293+312)/2=302,5
302,5*0,2=60,5

### Part 3: wrapping it all up and making an algorithm

So the first thing you should do is to determine the amount of data in each list, the number of lists, and how often you recieve data, the bigger the amount of data and the more often you recieve data, it would be reasonable to index your data. The way I would suggest is that for each list you save the highest and lowest valid number. If this is not the case you can skip this part and look at part 4 as you can basically run the algorithm against the whole list each time you recieve new data.

First add 4 values to a list, min price, max price, average price and threshold. The average price is (max price+min price)/2. After this you can use a % of the average price to determine a threshold for your prices, I will suggest 20% since it will result in a number close to the number you use which is 50, find the threshold by multiplying the average number with 0,2.

Depending on your data you can always chose to find a threshold based on 20% of the average of min value, max value and a new number ((min+max+new)/2*0,2), you can change this calculation if the difference should ever change.

When you recieve new numbers your algorithm should check the absolute number against the threshold.
Depending on the frequency of new numbers I would suggest this at a low frequency.

```
ProcessNumber(var value)
{
    if(absoluteValue(MinValue-value)<=MaxValue*0,2) //depending on how many numbers you want to be valid you can change the threshold, by doing this you allow the maximum value to change if the new number is valid but higher than max value
    {
        addNumber(value);
    }
    else
    {
        deleteNumber(value);
    }
}
```

If the process of retrieving new numbers happens very often you can add two numbers at once, if odd numbers occur 1/3 times I'd suggest the above method instead.

```
ProcessNumbers(var value1, var value2)
    {
    if(absoluteValue(value1-value2)<=threshold) //if you want the thresholdnumber to be valid too, use less than or equal to
        {
            addnumber(value1); 
            addnumber(value2); 
            return true
        }//If you have a method to add them
    else
        if(checkNumber(value1)) // returns true if valid)
            { //we now know value 1 is valid
                deleteNumber(value2); //because the check was false and we know value1 is valid value2 must be the invalid one
                addNumber(value1);
            }
        else if(checkNumber(value2))
            { //we now know value 2 is valid
                deleteNumber(value1);
                addNumber(value2);
            }
        else
            { //we now know both values are invalid
                deleteNumber(value1);
                deleteNumber(value2);
            }
    }
```

### Part 4: first run

You will need an algorithm for the first run, if there currently are no invalid numbers and you didn't skip you can ignore this part.

For the first run you should group the numbers to sorted lists by what threshold they are in.
You take two numbers at a time and see if the absolute value is below the threshold.

```
absolute = value1-value2;
threshold = value1+value2)/2*0.2;
if(absolute<threshold)
    AddToThreshold(threshold,value1,value2);
else
    AddToLater(value1,value2);
```

the AddTolater is a list that contains values you have to doublecheck since you don't know if value1, value2 or both values sent them into this list.
The addtothreshold makes sure that if there's a threshold group with a value higher than the threshold submitted the values will be submitted to this group.

Now you should have a few groups with thresholds, what you do now is take the lowest of the lowest group and take the lowest of the highest group and check if their absolute value is below their threshold, you can then use this threshold to figure out if other absolute values are below this particular threshold and sort them from each other, let's take your list and use the lowest threshold with the highest absolute number from two valid numbers.

Threshold:
(293+298)/2=295,5*0.2=59,1 (this is the threshold)

Highest possible absolute number from 2 valid numbers:
293-312=|19|

This became a really long post and I hope it can give you at least some inspiration, although it might not be necessary with that much processing if you do not have that many lists all of this might be an overkill unless you are planning something scalable.

best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is called outlier detection. There are statistical tests for this purpose. Beware anyway that nothing can guarantee 100% reliability.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier#Identifying_outliers